# Как привести объект базового типа к производному, зная Type?

Tags: c#

Упрощенно имею следующее:

```
Type type; //тип класса, производного от Request (в данном случае ConcretRequest)
Request request;
```

Нужно сделать следующее:

```
ConcretRequest concretRequest = (ConcretRequest)request;
```

Как это сделать?

**Update:**

Мне это нужно для передачи данных на сервер. Объекты классов, производных от `Request`, являются контейнерами для данных. На стороне клиента я их сериализую и создаю объект класса, содержащего результат сериализации и тип сериализованного объекта:

```
public class RequestPacket
{
    public Type type;
    public byte[] requestBytes;
}
```

Сериализую `RequestPacket` и отправляю на сервер. На сервере десериализую в `RequestPacket`. Далее мне необходимо десериализовать `requestBytes` в экземпляр класса, производного от `Request`.

У меня есть ощущение, что я изобретаю велосипед. Но никак не могу найти, как это можно сделать проще.

Comment: То есть вы не знаете тип во время компиляции? Окей, допустим, вы смогли привести тип — а что вы дальше будете делать?

Comment: а почему не сделать RequestPacket генериком и внутри хранить не тип и байт, а поле конкретного типа и сериализовать все вместе?

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за комментарий. Но я же все равно не могу создать экземпляр RequestPacket<T> на сервере не зная Т. Не могли бы Вы привести пример использования.

Comment: неа, не мог бы :) добавь больше подробностей в вопрос

Comment: Тогда я просто не понимаю, что Вы предлагаете. Предположим, я использую дженерик. На сервере мне нужно десериализовать RequestPacket<T> из byte[]. Но сервер-то не знает тип Т, а обработка объектов типа T происходит различными способами в зависимости от T. Например, запрос на проверку обновлений: передаются логин и пароль, сервер проверяет наличие пары в базе данных и возвращает обновления. Запрос на изменение никнейма: передаются логин, пароль, новый никнейм, сервер проверяет наличие логина и пароля в базе, меняет никнейм, отправляет подтверждение клиенту.

Comment: А разве сериализуется тип? Мне казалось, что объект. То есть в массиве байт (а затем и в поле `Request request`) у вас лежит готовый объект сразу нужного типа, который где-то далее при обработке нужно привести к конкретному типу. Пусть это будет `LoginRequest`. `if (type == typeof(LoginRequest)) { LoginRequest loginRequest = (LoginRequest)request; ... }`

Comment: @DmitryD., спасибо за ответ. Я правильно понимаю, что при десериализации можно сделать так `Request request = (Request)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);`, и далее в коде `if (type == typeof(LoginRequest)) { LoginRequest loginRequest = (LoginRequest)request; }`. Я думал, что при десериализации нельзя указывать родительский класс.

Comment: Я уверен, что можно. Попробуйте, и если получится, я оформлю это как ответ.

Comment: @DmitryD., действительно работает. Огромное спасибо. Жду ответа, чтобы отметить, как засчитанный.

Comment: @MaximRyazanov сделано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в массиве байт (а затем и в поле `Request request`) лежит готовый объект сразу нужного типа, который где-то далее при обработке нужно привести к конкретному типу.

Для примера, пусть это будет `LoginRequest`.

```
Request request = (Request)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);

if (type == typeof(LoginRequest))
{
    LoginRequest loginRequest = (LoginRequest)request;
    // ... дальнейшая работа с loginRequest ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
ConcretRequest concretRequest = request as ConcretRequest;
if(concretRequest != null)
{
//TODO:
}
```

Красиво и просто.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?